# unable to do squats

Tags: strength, squats

I am a college football player, I have been playing football since young age but I am not doing any kind of squat or strength exercises because whenever I do I become immobile for 15 min. So if you can please suggest me some exercises and something that can help. I dont think that only sprinting will help my football

Answer (score 2):

Can you define "immobile"? If you have an injury or condition you need to address that first. Otherwise Squats are a really technical exercise if you want to do them right. Most people have to start with a lot of flexibility and technique work before they can get serious.

Stretching your hamstrings, gluts, quads and ankles is probably where you need to start, unless there is an underlying medical condition causing you to tighten up.

How old are you?

Comment: Great questions, essential even.

Answer (score 0):

Strength would help in everything. So, squats and deadlifts are going to help you in any sport there is.

Are you sure your form is good or perfect? A video would help for us to analyze if there is any problem.